# add CSS animation to megamenu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I design mega menu using bootstrap 3.2 CSS Like this:

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
  background:#f0f0f0;
}
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
    margin-top:20px;
    border-top-left-radius:4px;
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    width:200px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.mega-dropdown {
  position: static !important;
  width:100%;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu {
    padding: 20px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu:before {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
    border-right: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 17px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 285px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu:after {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 17px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 19px solid transparent;
    border-left: 19px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -17px;
    left: 283px;
    z-index: 8;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #999;
  white-space: normal;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:hover,
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
  color: #428bca;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu form {
    margin:3px 20px;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

This worked for me but i need to Add css animate for show and hide dropdown like this (or any css3 animated :

```
@-webkit-keyframes showSubMenu {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0,0);
    }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1,1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hideSubMenu {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1,1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0,0);
  }
}
```

live Preview : http://jsfiddle.net/ubf9bk1y/

How do add CSS animated for show and hide dropdown?!

Comment: @MarcB: How do add CSS animated for show and hide dropdown?!

Comment: You don't need animations for this mate. Just transitions would do. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/ubf9bk1y/1/) is a sample. Note that this sample overrides some of Bootstrap's default settings. I am not much into Bootstrap and hence don't know if there is some built-in options for achieving the same. I will add this as answer if you are Ok with this as a solution :)